# C# remove string inside bounderies

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, string-matching

sorry if this is duplicate or something but i was unable to find solution in c# for my problem. I have c# `string` that lookl like this:

`string aa = "First Example (first to delete) , Second example ( Second to delete ) , Thrird Example ( Third to delete )"`

From this string I want to delete everything that is inside `( SOME INPUT )` with `(` and `)`.

Problem is that I dont know what this `SOME INPUT` is. I only know that it is inside `()`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Ok, I am going to take a look at those links. I will try better next time. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jnhszs

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    var text = "First Example (first to delete) , Second example ( Second to delete ) , Thrird Example ( Third to delete )";

    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\([^)]*\)", "");
    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s{2,}", " ");

    Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Output: First Example , Second example , Thrird Example